# How do I get the code via reflection of a protected member in a derived class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I am trying to get the code of a protected method of a derived class via reflection.

We have a base class with some overridable protected methods, the one I am interested in is **DefineSubdomain**.

The method looks like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub DefineSubdomains()
    With SubdomainDefs
        .Add("PurchaseOrderItemLine", requiredForAdd:=False)
        .Add("PurchaseOrderMiscLine", requiredForAdd:=False)
        .Add("PurchaseOrderWOLine", requiredForAdd:=False)
    End With
End Sub
```

I wish to retrieve the first arguments to the Add method.  I can get a reference to the method, but I can't figure out how to read the code.  I have used this:

```
    SomeAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(mconAppPath & "\AO_PurchaseOrder.dll")

    Types = SomeAssembly.GetTypes
    For Each ThisType In Types

        If ThisType.IsClass Then

            If ThisType.Name = "AO_PurchaseOrder.imsAO_PurchaseOrder" Then
                ThisFunction = ThisType.GetMethod("DefineSubdomains", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                'What now?
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

For the example I only need the text "PurchaseOrder", "PurchaseOrderMiscLine" & "PurchaseOrderWOLine".  There are over 700 domains and subdomains in this app which is why I am trying to view the dependencies with code.  I have the source code but the files for the classes are not named consistent and it seemed easier with reflection.  If anyone has an idea reading the source code that may be easier im open to it.  But some of the projects have the classes named differently than the domain name and some have them in separate directories.  The only meta data I have for the domains is assembly name and class name.

Comment: "Reading the code" might be much more complicated than you think. Can you just look at the items inside the SubdomainDefs list?

Comment: The objects can not be instantiated on their own, so no I can not.

Comment: What type is `SubdomainDefs` and where is it defined in the class that contains the `DefineSubdomains` method? It appears to be a Dictionary of some sort.  You could probably use reflection to get a direct reference to that object and access it data directly.

Comment: SubdomainDefs is an IntuitiveAppObjectFramework2.imsSubdomainDefs object.  It appears to inherit from hashtable.  CodeReflect shows "extends [mscorlib]System.Collections.Hashtable."  By the way, I can view the information I need from code reflect so I know it can be done.